# Expose Service in Kubernetes using Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am new to Kubernetes. I have deployed a Node API in my local machine with the help of minikube. Below is the nodejs service:
[image]

Spec in node-service.yaml

```
spec:
 type: NodePort
 ports:
  - name: "8000"
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
```

Even tried with LoadBalancer, no luck.
I have created a basic ingress using the below file:

```js
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: nodejs
              servicePort: 8000
```

But I am unable to expose this service.
[image]

ADDRESS is not bound. Please suggest a possible solution that works on my local machine. If there is any other solution to expose my api over http please point me to a resource where I can get more information about it.

GitHub Link:
[Basic Node Mongo Kubernetes Setup](https://github.com/abhilashdk2016/Node_Mongo_Kubernetes)

Comment: do you have an ingress controller running? `kubectl -n kube-system get pods `

Comment: The only controller I see is `kube-controller-manager-minikube`.

Comment: I have added my GitHub Repo Link.

Comment: This [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) will help you to setup Ingress in minikube.

Comment: @Ansil Thanks for the documentation link. Enabling ingress while using minikube worked for me.

Comment: @AbhilashDK , could you please create an answer to your question on what was wrong. That'll help next person to solve the issue that is similar

Answer (score 1):

Based in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) I enabled ingress on my minikube cluster by running the command `minikube addons enable ingress`. This solved my issue.